# sqlite3 : SQL statement to update a table not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, sqlite

For update a table, I write::update  set =\"%@\" WHERE =\"%@\"",col1Value,col2Value];

But,this is not working. Please help.

My code is below:

```
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE AssemblyAssessment SET countedunits=\"%@\" WHERE assemblyid=\"%@\"",self.SAcountedunits,self.asmbIdStr];
    const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(ipadSites,query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {

            if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
            {
                NSLog(@"done...");

            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"not done...");
            }


        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(ipadSites);
    }
```

Comment: try with this query UPDATE AssemblyAssessment SET countedunits="%@" WHERE assemblyid="%@"

Comment: Call [`sqlite3_errmsg`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html).

Comment: what is the type of `countedunits` and `assemblyid` ?

Comment: Does the query string look like you expect it should look like?

Answer (score 1):

1. You should use `"?"` in your prepared statement and use [`sqlite3_bind_text`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) then to bind the string values, instead of using `stringWithFormat` and `%@`. This way you will **prevent SQL injections** and security issues in your SQL requests (e.g. in case your string contains quotes or other stuff).
2. For your problem, please be more precise than "it doesn't work". Does it return an error code, in which case which one? Does it return with an OK status but your db isn't working? What are the types of your variables? What are the values of your temporary variables like `querySQL`, did you try to put breakpoints in your code to check what is happening? Etc, etc.

Answer (score 0):

what is not working exactly. You can try to print error message like this:

```
NSLog(@"%s",sqlite3_errmsg(ipadSites));
```

also, for such one-line requests you can use sqlite3_exec() function:

```
sqlite3_exec(ipadSites, query_stmt, NULL,NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: (sqlite3_prepare_v2(ipadSites,query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)  i'm not getting any output from this position

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted shows you getting the path to the database file but there is no code to open the database. You need to make a call to `sqlite3_open_v2` before you attempt to prepare the statement or execute the query.

It's also a bad idea to use a string format to build the query. Your query should be:

```
const char *query_stmt = "UPDATE AssemblyAssessment SET countedunits = ? WHERE assemblyid = ?";
```

Prepare that statement, then make use of the appropriate `sqlite3_bind_xxx` methods to bind the two values to the query. This is a much safer approach. It takes care of properly quoting and escaping the values.